# How to prevent an image from resizing within a grid when browser is resized

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm pretty new to front end coding and am just working on a practice site to help get used to the code. In this site I'm using a bootstrap grid with an image in the left column. What I'm trying to do is prevent the image size and position from changing when the browser size is changed, like this website does in their "Our Famous Freebies section" http://presentation.creative-tim.com/. Notice how the images in the grid remain the same size, and stay in the same position before the page break when the browser is resized.

What my image does is continuously resizes as the browser size is changed. I've tried changing all of the heights from % to px with no luck. At the moment I'm just working with the large and medium sized browser windows. I haven't tried styling the small or x-small sized windows yet. Below is my HTML and CSS.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Welcome to Philadelphia</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/stylesheets/athletics.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="full-contain">
    <div class="row row-one">
      <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 top-col">
        <img class="img-responsive center-block" src="http://logos-
                 download.com/wp-
          content/uploads/2016/04/Philadelphia_Phillies_logo_logotype.png">
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 top-col">This is a div</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row row-two">
      <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 mid-col">This is a div</div>
      <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 mid-col">This is a div</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row row-three">
      <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 btm-col">This is a div</div>
      <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 btm-col">This is a div</div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

```css
.top-col {
  background-color: #003086;
  height: 733px;
  color: white;
}

.mid-col {
  background-color: #003B48;
  height: 733px;
  color: white;
}

.btm-col {
  background-color: #F4793E;
  height: 733px;
  color: white;
}

.row-one {
  height: 733px;
}

.row-two {
  height: 733px;
}

.row-three {
  height: 733px;
}

body {
  height: 733px;
}

html {
  height: 733px;
}

.full-contain {
  width: 100%;
  height: 733px;
}
```

Excuse the rough appearance. Like I said I'm a beginner.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The img-responsive Bootstrap class causes your image to resize with the parent element. Take that class away and style your img element in your CSS and it will do what you would like.